# Make objects in the image in one line

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a problem.

So, I have this image, and I want put all of the numbers onto one line:
[image]

But I only got this:
[image]

As you can see, if it is 1, 0, 7 - all is fine, but with 4 and 3...

My code:

```
def reshape_img(self):
    width, height = self.img.size
    new_img_list = []
    for x in range(width):
        white_y = 0
        start_nr = False
        for y in range(height):
            red, green, blue = self.img.getpixel((x, y))  # Current color
            if red != 255:
                start_nr = True
                new_y = y - white_y + 5
                new_img_list.append((x, new_y, (red, green, blue)))
            elif red == 255 and not start_nr:
                white_y += 1
    return new_img_list

def new_image(image_list):
    background = (255, 255, 255, 255)
    img = Image.new('RGB', (545, 20), background)
    pixels = img.load()
    for d in image_list:
        pixels[d[0], d[1]] = d[2]
    img.save('img2.png')
```

Comment: Could you create an example just with `4`? See how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adjusting each column of pixels based on the first non-white pixel of just that column, look at columns adjacent plus or minus a certain range (enough to cover an entire digit) and take the minimum of all of them. This way the digits will move up and down as a block, and not be distorted by different columns moving different amounts. You can do it in a couple of passes, using a list to store the minimums:

```
def reshape_img(self):
    width, height = self.img.size
    y_start = [height] * width

    # find the first non-white pixel of each column (checking only red channel):
    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            red, green, blue = self.img.getpixel((x, y))  # Current color
            if red != 255:
               y_start[x] = y
               break

    new_img_list = []
    for x in range(width):
        # find minimum of adjacent columns +/- 5 left and right:
        white_y = min(y_start[min(0,x-5):max(width-1:x+5)])
        for y in range(white_y, height):
            red, green, blue = self.img.getpixel((x, y))  # Current color
            if red != 255:
                new_y = y - white_y + 5
                new_img_list.append((x, new_y, (red, green, blue)))
    return new_img_list
```

(untested code)

This algorithm relies on there being spaces between the digits (as there are in your image), you would have to adjust the number of adjacent columns based on the size and spacing of the digits if they changed. You could make it more robust by only taking the minimum of a contiguous block of non-all-white columns, so if there is an all white column then columns on one side can't affect columns on the other.